# Sharing Databases and Tables between users in MySQL

Tags: mysql, security

I want to know how it is possible to share a database tables between multiple users/user groups, I mean, SQL Server has a security feature that we can create user groups and assign users to them, then we can give each user group permissions for tables in a database/schema. So, a user from visitors usergroup can't read sensitive admin tables, or a visitor can read categories but can't insert/update categories table but users from admin user group can.

Comment: You should read the mysql manual on access priviele system and user account management first and then ask specific question if sg is still unclear: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-system.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-account-management.html

Comment: Btw, in mysql there are no groups or roles, only users.

Answer (score 1):

[https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/roles/](MariaDB 10.0.5 has Roles); see if they provide what you desire.

(Yes, MariaDB is essentially compatible with MySQL; Roles is an extra feature.)